# Why use matchMedia when you can just check if an element is visible?

Tags: javascript, media-queries, matchmedia

I think matchMedia is not supported in IE9 but media queries are.

I may be missing the point here but why use matchMedia when you can simply add the following code to your style sheet

```
.desktop_view{display:block;}
.mobile_view{display:none;}

@media all and (max-width: 700px){
    .desktop_view{display:none;}
    .mobile_view{display:block;}
}
```

and then check for the condition in your Javascript as follows?

```
if($("div.desktop_view").is(":visible")){
    // Do something applicable to desktops
}
```

Comment: So you are asking, why not add more code that achieves the same thing in a more convoluted way, when there now exists a dedicated method for this ...? Because we want to write modern code, and not drag solutions from the stone ages along for all eternity, just so as to take massively outdated browsers along the ride, that are huge security disasters. (And in a situation where we actually "have to" and there's no way around that, we would probably much rather use a polyfill in most cases.)

Comment: Wanted reassurance that matchMedia was not doing anything I had overlooked. Seems like I have not. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

[`window.matchMedia`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/matchMedia) is more powerful than you let on. Not only does it allow you to use the browser's native media query-parsing programmatically, but the return object ([`MediaQueryList`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MediaQueryList)) lets you listen to events (via [`onchange`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MediaQueryList/onchange)) that correspond to changes in the user's viewport.

Per [MDN Web Docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MediaQueryList):

> This makes it possible to observe a document to detect when its media queries change, instead of polling the values periodically, and allows you to programmatically make changes to a document based on media query status.

This event handler allows you to develop more complex functionality than simply invoking style changes—e.g., tracking mobile users who rotate to landscape, as a barometer of whether your site is well-designed for portrait use.

Comment: I implemented your 'listening to onchange events' suggestion and it worked well. However the company for whom I am developing the application has many visitors to their site who use old versions of browsers. I have had a rethink and now see that my application can be configured using media queries alone without the need for less supported matchMedia so that correct element layout on the page for large desktops and small mobiles can simply be checked by rotating a tablet between portrait and landscape. I will however keep matchmedia and use of onchange in mind for other applications. Thanks.